# SharePoint Online Integrated Workflow Task List Permission Break

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sharepoint-online

I am currently working on SharePoint integrated workflow in Visual Studio 2015. Workflow is manually attached to a list after deploying the app.

I want to break the task list permission so a user with contributor permission can not approve the task. But when attaching I cannot select a task list in host web and in the workflow I cannot get the app web URL to access the task list reside in the app web(to break permission using REST).If I can attach a task list in host web, It can be accessed inside the workflow.

Please let me know if there is a solution, or a dependable source saying this is not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the task list inside app-web you can use 
http:// server-name/app-name/lists/listname

Comment: I do not understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's no one activity way of getting the id based appweb url in a Visual Studio integrated workflow - the WebUri is the host url.

Essentially, though, the app web is actually a subsite of the site collection (if the app was installed at site collection level and not deployed from the App Catalog to multiple site collections). So if one builds the url for a REST call like
`<hostwebUrl>/<appname>/_api/web`, you will be able to access the REST API of the appweb.

If you would construct the above link for browser access, though, the user is redirected to the correct, ID based url of the app web. 
For example, in the notification e-mail you construct a Url to a task item in the app web using only the host web url:
`<hostweburl>/<app_path>/Lists/WorkflowTasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=1`

When the user clicks that link, automatically gets redirected to:
`<appweburl>/<app_path>/Lists/WorkflowTasks/EditForm.aspx?ID=1`

Haven't measured the time impact of the redirect though.